# Example of homeomorphic-conjugate maps that is not $C^1$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, analysis, examples-counterexamples

> Is there a simple (non-trivial) example of smooth $f,g:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ that are topological conjugate via a homeomorphism $h$ (i.e. $f\circ h = h\circ g$) such that $h$ is not $C^1$?

Comment: Lots of examples for  $f\equiv 0, g \equiv 0.$

Comment: It would be good to make clear in the statement exactly what you are looking for.

Comment: @zhw Just a simple non-trivial example. Nothing specific.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: Play around with

$$\begin{cases} f(x) = 0& x\le 0\\ f(x) = e^{-1/x}& x > 0 \end{cases}$$

and

$$\begin{cases} h(x) = x& x\le 0\\ h(x) = 2x & x > 0 \end{cases}$$